# Call function from thread created via CreateRemoteThread

Tags: c++, c, dll, dll-injection

I'm studying dll injection and so far I managed to inject a dll in a process causing the message box to show up.

The part I didn't quite understand, even after tons of readings and research, is how I pass a parameter to the dll, or call a specific function within it.

The dll:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool WINAPI
DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDll, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{

switch (fdwReason)
{
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hello World!", "Dll says:", MB_OK);

    break;
    }

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
}

return true;
}
```

The injection:

```
char dllPath[] = "sampleDll.dll";

// For dll path injection.
int memAmountToAllocate = strlen(dllPath);

LPVOID dllPathAddress = VirtualAllocEx(procHandle, 0, memAmountToAllocated, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

FARPROC loadLibraryAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

WriteProcessMemory(procHandle, dllPathAddress, dllPath, memAmountToAllocated, 0);

// creating a thread that will call LoadLibraryA with allocMemAddress as argument
CreateRemoteThread(procHandle, 0, 0, loadLibraryAddr, dllPathAddress, 0, 0);
```

As I said, the injection works fine, i.e. the message box appears.
But say I have a method in the dll `foo(LPVOID ptrToData)`. How can I call the `foo` function?
I have the address of the function I want to execute on the target process, it is an adding function, so I need to pass x and y.

I can call the function like this

```
          _asm
        {
            push 0;
            push 0x7;
            mov ecx, esi;
            mov eax, 0x41367C;
            call eax;
        }
```

however the values for `push` must come from the injecting process.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why can't you call the function normally, seeing as it's part of the same DLL's code (unless I've misunderstood)? If it's not part of the DLL's code then couldn't you do the same as with injecting, i.e. make your DLL get the function address and then call it?

Comment: The function would be in my dll, yes, but I eant to call it programatically, with parameters.

Comment: Call it from where, your DLL or the process that created the remote thread?

Comment: I have my program running, lets call it process A.
Process A injects dll into another process, process B.
Now that my dll is injected, I need to call the method Add() that is inside the injected dll from process A.

Comment: Hmm. I've done this but in a rather clumsy way. Basically I created a pipe in process A, and the injected DLL connected to the pipe. That allowed me to communicate with the DLL via the pipe and tell it what to do. There's probably a better way though...

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do. I don't think there is a better way. I think it's either pipes or sockets (or any other protocol). =/
I'm working with C# however, so I think it will take a bit of work to make C# wcf work in a dll

Comment: I did it in C# as well, well my process was C# and the DLL was C. Named pipe communication between the two is relatively straightforward and I just created some arbitrary rules for communication etc, so I was able to tell it to call x function and could feed it parameters as well (though my parameters were always DWORDs which probably simplified things). So it can definitely be done like that.

Comment: My parameters are mere integers, so I think this particular point won't be a problem. I have a wcf service up and running with an opened pipe net.pipe://localhost/injectpipe. Now I need to figure out a way to connect to if from my dll. Do you mind sharing this piece of code?

Comment: Sure, check this out: http://pastebin.com/BrFd99EP I never quite got around to finishing it so it's a bit rough but it's worked well for me in my half-finished application. DllMain starts a new thread, because you can't block DllMain otherwise you can cause a deadlock. So DllMain starts a new thread and exits, and the new thread gets the pipe name and starts peeking for data. I communicate with it in single bytes, and certain ones correspond to commands. And you can see at certain points I call a function to read a DWORD from the pipe, and I use certain bytes as start/end when sending a DWORD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to use an IPC mechanism to allow my main application and dll to communicate.
I used a named pipe.

I created the pipe in C# and then when I inject the dll I connect to the pipe.